# Using CDK deploy cannot read temporary S3 bucket that holds Lambda Code

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

When I deploy a Lambda "code" using CDK the deploy process (cloudformation running under presumably my user) does not have seem to have access to the bucket that holds the Lambda code.

I followed this tutorial: https://intro-to-cdk.workshop.aws/what-is-cdk.html and see this error when I run `cdk deploy`:

`Lambda8C48573D) Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-19kn1ypcmzq2q/assets/5327df`

Lambda Code:

```
const handler = new lambda.Function(this, "TimestreamLambda", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../resources')),
      handler: "index.hello_world",
      ...
```

cdk *and* @aws-cdk version is 1.73.0 but I also tried with 1.71.0

Notes:

- I see the bucket under my account (in my region).
- When logged into this account I can see and download the asset file
- the downloaded zip file has the correct contents.

More error details:

```
12/24 | 9:15:19 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Lambda::Function                 | TimestreamLambda (TimestreamLambda8C48573D) Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-28hiljazvaim/assets/5327df740bdc9c380ff567xxxxxxxxxxx7a68a.zip. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 1b813776-7647-4767-89bc-XXXXXXXXX; Proxy: null)
    new Function (/Users/<user>/dev/cdk/cdk-workshop/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/function.ts:593:35)
    \_ new CdkWorkshopStack (/Users/<user>/dev/cdk/cdk-workshop/lib/cdk-workshop-stack.ts:33:21)
```

I also see this (using the **-v** option) during deploy:

```
env: {
  CDK_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-west-2',
  CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT: '94646XXXXX',
  CDK_CONTEXT_JSON: '{"@aws-cdk/core:enableStackNameDuplicates":"true","aws-cdk:enableDiffNoFail":"true","@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports":"true","aws:cdk:enable-path-metadata":true,"aws:cdk:enable-asset-metadata":true,"aws:cdk:version-reporting":true,"aws:cdk:bundling-stacks":["*"]}',
  CDK_OUTDIR: 'cdk.out',
  CDK_CLI_ASM_VERSION: '7.0.0',
  CDK_CLI_VERSION: '1.73.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this was an issue with the internal authentication system my company uses to access AWS. Instead of using my regular AWS account to access I had to create a temporary account (which also sets a temporary token).